# How to loop in output of postgresql query into a variable using windows batch

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a multi line SQL code where I want to store a single column with multiple rows into a variable. Can someone please help me with this? 
I am new to batch and learning but this is something I am finding difficulty with.

Heres what my SQl query in batch looks like:

SQl Query:
Select email,username 
from table1,table2, table3 
where table1.id = table2.id 
and table1.id=table3.id
and table1.somefilter
and table2.somefilter;
I am storing the output of the same into a folder which is denoted below as "C:\filelocation"

psql -d Database -p 8000 -U username -t -A -f C:\filelocation -o "C:\text.txt"

Output: 
abc@abc.com abc
xyz@abc.com xyz

So this is a list of email addresses and their associated usernames. So, I would like to put them in a variable.

I am using -f as it is a multi line sql query with 2 different columns and multiple rows.

I have managed to get the output of the query into a folder, but what I really want is that I want to loop them into a variable.

Thanks

Comment: please post a example on how the output is, and what is the information you want to retrieve so we may help you. we have not a crystal ball to guess what exactly you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Hey elzooilogico, I hope this helps. I apologize for the not providing all the details required. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the output should be

```
abc@abc.com abc 
xyz@abc.com xyz
...
```

You only need to parse the output file as in

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (C:\text.txt) do (
  echo(Email address is: %%a
  echo(Username is:      %%b
)
```

or, if you want to want to grab them into variables

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem grab fields into variables 
set /a counter=0
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in (C:\text.txt) do (
  set /a counter+=1
  set "eMail_!counter!=%%a"
  set "uName_!counter!=%%b"
)

rem process them
for /L %%i in (1,1,!counter!) do (
  rem whatever you wanna do
  echo(Email address is: !eMail_%%i!
  echo(Username is:      !uName_%%i!
)
Endlocal
```

This works if each pair is in a single line and there is a space between then, if the separator is a **comma** just change `"tokens=1,2 delims= "` to `"tokens=1,2 delims=,"`

Comment: Thanks for the solutions!! Cheers!!